# Does an app exist for the iPhone that sends a push notification if it detects that the device has physically been moved?

Tags: iphone, ios

Does an iPhone app exist that sends a push notification if accelerometer movement is detected? A good use case for this would be in environments where a phone is left unattended - I'm sure I saw an app a while ago that does this, but can't find any references whatsoever now!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *Find My*-app to let a friend know when your location changes or also get a notification when your friend’s location changes.

More about *Find My*-app [www.support.apple.com](https://support.apple.com/en-za/guide/ipad/ipad4c370380/ipados)